# best way to write code of bool that check 6 functions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, c#-4.0, boolean

I have this code:

```
          bool validInput = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reg_name_tbx.Text)
               && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reg_adr_tbx.Text)
           && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reg_phn_tbx.Text)
           && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reg_pwr_tbx.Text)
           && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reg_email_tbx.Text)
           && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reg_type_cbx.Text);
```

Is there a better way to write this?
It is checking that all text boxes have valid input from the user..

Comment: Better is subjective. What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: I am wondering if there is a shorter, more efficient way.

Comment: Oftentimes shorter (I am assuming you mean terse) and more efficient are diametrically opposed. What you have is about as performant as you will get. If you are looking to shorten the amount of code, you can encapsulate the the check in another method, but it doesn't actually buy you much and it makes the code less performant.

Comment: define "better". because that's very subjective. while this code is somewhat verbose, it's _clear_ to read. so except if you need to write this sort of code _very often,_ i see no problems. but you might like the option of putting your texts (or textboxes) in an array and use `.Any()`

Comment: It is tempting to close this question on the grounds it is opinionated, but I can understand why you really look for a less verbose way if this kind of situation happens often. Perhaps a method that takes a variable number of arguments and check they're all nonEmpty, but you may have to write it yourself.

Comment: seems your code is straightforward, logically clear, why even bother to 'optimize' it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot make your code any more *performant* than it already is. There is no overload for `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` that takes multiple parameters and you will have to check each string individually.

That said, if you want to make the code more terse, you can encapsulate the check in a method that takes an array of strings:

```
public bool DoAllStringsHaveContent(params string[] input)
{
    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
            return false;
    }
        
    return true;
}
```

You can then call it like so:

```
bool validInput = DoAllStringsHaveContent(reg_name_tbx.Text,
    reg_adr_tbx.Text, reg_phn_tbx.Text, reg_pwr_tbx.Text,
    reg_email_tbx.Text, reg_type_cbx.Text);
```

And for completeness' sake, if you want to do this in a "one-liner" without a reusable method, you can use LINQ:

```
bool validInput = new string[] 
    {
        reg_name_tbx.Text, reg_adr_tbx.Text, reg_phn_tbx.Text,
        reg_pwr_tbx.Text, reg_email_tbx.Text, reg_type_cbx.Text
    }.All(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the textboxes are all on the form:

```
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(tb => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
```

If they're in a panel, replace `this` with the name of the panel

If you have other textboxes that shouldn't be included you can add some other condition that reduces the candidate textboxes to just those you're interested in; perhaps:

```
 this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(tb => tb.Name.StartsWith("reg") && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
```